# What to do after cancelled "rm -rf /usr/" on Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, rm, pacman, integrity

So I just did this on my up-to-date Arch system:

```
[anna@home ~]$ sudo rm -rf /usr/
^C[anna@home ~]$ ^C
[anna@home ~]$ ^C
```

I terminated the `rm` very quickly. I can't find anything wrong with `/usr/` by eye.

What options are there to see if any damage was done? Is there some pacman integrity check that I should run? Any specific files I should check to make sure that the system can start again?

From now on, I'll keep backups of the *entire* system.

Comment: Reinstall all packages. I don't know arch, but on debian, I'd do `apt-get install --reinstall list-of-all-packages-here`, you should do the arch equivalent.

Comment: *I can't find anything wrong with /usr/ by eye.* Considering there are thousands of files in there, you'd only notice by eyeballing if a noticable percentage were gone.  But it might only take one to cause problems. :(

Comment: @goldilocks That basically meant that at least something is left in /usr/bin and /usr/lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Dennis Kaarsemaker wrote the right thing: reinstall all packages.

A few minutes googling revealed this [Arch wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman_Tips#Reinstalling_all_packages), with a section on reinstalling all packages. Since you didn't delete `/var/cache/pacman/pkg`, the process should happen locally.  The command looks like this:

```
pacman -Qenq | pacman -S -
```

`pacamn -Qeng` only lists "explicitly installed", "native" packages by group. It may miss some packages from "extra" or "community" repositories, or any AUR packages you had installed. I'm personally afraid to try this, because my Arch installs are working, but

```
pacman -Qn | awk '{print $1}' | pacman -S -
```

might reinstall every single package it can. I'm not sure how it would handle a dependency that gets installed explictly later in the process.  You might end up reinstalling packages that have already gotten re-installed as a dependency.

If you managed to delete `pacman`, I think the process just might involve a partial "new install" using the Arch install ISO, but I'm scared to recommend that.

Comment: Thanks. `pacman` is fortunately still there.

Comment: @Anna - please update your question if and when you try something, so that at least I know what to do for my Arch installations.  I think you've hit a corner case - not many people have done what you've done, at least publically. Upvoted answers might be wrong answers in your situation.

Comment: I tried to reinstall everything with your first command and ended up with 8000 lines of "xorg-server-devel: /usr/include/xorg/xorg-server.h exists in filesystem" (with different package names and filenames). `pacman -Qo` says that no package owns those files.

Comment: All of those files except for four lie in /usr/. Most exist, though.

Comment: It turns out that only a couple packages (kdebase-runtime
kdeutils-kwallet
make
mercurial
oxygen-icons-svg
xorg-server-common
xorg-server-devel) contained those 8000 files. I reinstalled them successfully using `--force` and am again reinstalling all the packages with your first command now.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to (re)install all packages you can do a trick: check `/var/lib/pacman/local`'s subdirectories, and their `files`, which contains all installed files per package.

So a simple, not tested (and not perfect) script:

```
cd /var/lib/pacman
for package in *; do
    for file in $(grep ^usr ${package}/files); do
        [ -e "/${file}" ] || echo Bad package: ${package}
    done
done
```

You can improve this script (maybe if `${file}` doesn't exist, run `pacman -S ${package}` and continue) but I think the main idea isn't too bad :)